# Hook "wp_trash_post" executing multiple time in case of bulk trash products

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am currently using hook `wp_trash_post` to trigger my custom API when a WooCommerce Product is trashed.
This is working fine for the case of single trash.

But, in case of Bulk trash this event is executing multiple times. for example if 3 products are selected to trash then this event will trigger 3 times.

I need different event for Bulk Trash which will execute one time but having all of product ids.
Hopefully it is clear to understand.
Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

### Custom (database) Queue

One way would be to create a custom database table, and write to it the product id, each time a product is trashed via the `trashed_post` hook.

Then you can bulk process the collected trashed product ids via e.g. wp-cron and the user will not be affected by that potentially heavy processing.

With a real cron (not wp-cron) you could better control the timing/frequency of the processing.

This approach should also work if the products are trashed e.g. via wp-cli.

Similarly one could remove a product id from the custom table (or flag it) when the `untrashed_post` hook is fired for products.

### PHP Class and WP Hooks

One might also create a PHP class and use it to hook into `trashed_post`/`untrashed_post` and collect (e.g. via PHP queue object within the class) all product ids and then at a later hook, process all at once. The user might notice this for heavy processing or slow external API requests, unless it uses some async workarounds or in addition uses the custom database approach mentioned above.